# How should my redux helpers reference dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `redux` and `redux-thunk`. In a lot of my action creators I use helpers in which I pass `dispatch` to, I'm wondering if this is bad practice or an anti-pattern or can I avoid passing `dispatch` around like this.

For instance, I have an action creator like so:

```
import * from "./helpers";

export const listenForMessages = () => async (dispatch) => {
    helpers.updateListening(true, dispatch);
}
```

And I have a helper inside `helpers.js` like so:

```
export const updateListening(isListening = false, dispatch) {
   // do something interesting
   disptach(...);
}
```

I'd like to avoid having to pass dispatch around. It feels ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `dispatch(someAction)` in `updateListening`, make it return the action object instead:

```
export const updateListening(isListening = false) {
   // do something interesting
   return { type: SOME_ACTION, payload };
}
```

This makes `updateListening` just like any other action creators, so you can dispatch the action in the caller with:

```
export const listenForMessages = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(helpers.updateListening(true)); // or `bindActionCreators`
}
```

If `updateListening` needs to complete async calls before dispatching, then you can either return a promise and `await` it in `listenForMessages`, or turn it into an async action creator just like your `listenForMessages`, then you can dispatch it in exactly the same way: `dispatch(helpers.updateListening(true))`.

Answer (score 0):

As @riwu said, passing `dispatch` down is redundant, you can have helpers which simply return an action object.
Additionally, if you are using `react-redux`, action creators can be wrapped into dispatch automatically if you pass them as an object to `mapDispatchToProps`.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: Thanks for the link!